# Failed to install apk in emulator

Tags: android, apk, android-virtual-device

When ever I am trying to run the application in emulator it will run for the first time, from the second time onward it will fail,then i will close avd and i will start avd again.
 I changed the ADB Connection Timeout twice, no change I restarted eclispe then also same porblem, for the first time only application will run.. then fail.

how to solve this

this is the error

```
[2014-07-16 15:47:37 - Hydroponic] ------------------------------
[2014-07-16 15:47:37 - Hydroponic] Android Launch!
[2014-07-16 15:47:37 - Hydroponic] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-16 15:47:37 - Hydroponic] Performing com.tcs.ignite.hydroponic.ManualLogging activity launch
[2014-07-16 15:47:37 - Hydroponic] Uploading Hydroponic.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-07-16 15:47:38 - Hydroponic] Launch error: timeout
[2014-07-16 15:48:27 - Hydroponic] Failed to install Hydroponic.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
[2014-07-16 15:48:27 - Hydroponic] Launch failed on device: MyDevice
[2014-07-16 15:48:27 - Hydroponic] Starting activity com.tcs.ignite.hydroponic.ManualLogging on device emulator-5554
[2014-07-16 15:49:18 - Hydroponic] Launch error: timeout
[2014-07-16 15:53:39 - Hydroponic] ------------------------------
[2014-07-16 15:53:39 - Hydroponic] Android Launch!
[2014-07-16 15:53:39 - Hydroponic] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-16 15:53:39 - Hydroponic] Performing com.tcs.ignite.hydroponic.ManualLogging activity launch
[2014-07-16 15:53:39 - Hydroponic] Uploading Hydroponic.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-07-16 15:54:30 - Hydroponic] Failed to install Hydroponic.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
[2014-07-16 15:54:30 - Hydroponic] Launch failed on device: MyDevice
[2014-07-16 15:54:30 - Hydroponic] Starting activity com.tcs.ignite.hydroponic.ManualLogging on device emulator-5554
```

Comment: It is timeout related error, I have posted solution below as an answer

Comment: @Badrul I changed my ADB Connection Timeout (ms) to 10000ms first ,still the same problem, then changed to 50000ms still same no change

Comment: what is heap size of your emulator?

Comment: heap size of my emulator is 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the ADB connection timeout. I think it defaults that to 5000ms, you can change it to 10000ms to get rid of that problem.

If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through

Window-> Preferences -> Android -> DDMS -> ADB Connection Timeout (ms)

If the above solution doesn't work try this:

End this process adb.exe using taskmanager and restart your emulator

Or even try rebooting your PC

Comment: Keep increasing time, try restarting you emulator also it should work. As per your logcat error is related to timeout only. If after trying it still doesn't work let me know